# How do I properly structure Templates and include them in the settings in Django 1.8.6?

Tags: python, django

So, here is my current structure:

```
django_project/
  home_app/
    __init__.py
    migrations/
    templates/
      home_app/
        base.html
    admin.py
    models.py
    views.py
  project_backend/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    url.py
    wsgi.py
```

Now in home_app/views.py I have this very simple piece of code:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home/base.html"
```

and in the settings.py I set up my templates like this:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'home_app', 'templates'),
            # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app_name', 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

This works fine, and I am quite happy using the app/templates/app/some_temp.html approach, but this only works when I include the OS.path.joins for all the apps and templates, as far as I can see. Is there a way to register this structure in the settings by default and I am just overlooking it?

This is just no very pretty and I feel like it would be bad practice to write that down for every single app.:

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'home_app', 'templates')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `'APP_DIRS': True`, so you shouldn't have to edit `DIRS` to use templates in the `home_app/templates/` directory, as long as `home_app` is in your installed apps.

If you have a template,

```
home_app/templates/home_app/base.html
```

then you should use it with:

```
template_name = "home_app/base.html"
```

You currently have,

```
template_name = "home/base.html"
```

which isn't consistent.

Comment: plus `'DIRS`' is used when you have templates other than your custom installed apps so you give those paths in `'DIRS'` as list

Comment: Oh my god, thank you. I totally blanked out there for a sec and just forgot to put the app into my install apps! So silly of me.